# Are there any performance differences between color names or hexa values in css?

Tags: css, performance

Color properties in CSS can accept color names ( white, pink, etc) or hexadecimal values ( #FFF , #669966 , etc) or RGB.

But not all the color names are standard for all browsers. There are tests like [CSS color names vs hex codes](http://jsperf.com/css-color-names-vs-hex-codes/3), (my results is better hexadecimal) , so is it always better to use hexadecimal than other two options?

Edit: Other duplicate questions is about personal preferences, this is about performance.

Comment: If not all the color names are standard for all browsers, I think you have your answer. Performance is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting away the color names, the hex values and RGB are pretty much the same.

But the result shows that Hex codes are slightly faster (not that much to worry about).

For example, Firefox 11 does 15,400 operations of hex code but 14,900 of rgb in a second.

So, that is not much to worry about. You won't even notice that.

Answer (score 1):

You have sort of already answered your own question... "Not all color names are standard." It is best to get used to use the 6 character hex codes for color. It is explicit and there is no confusion. I have seen some versions of IE mess up with 3 digit hex codes also.

Hex codes are also better because there are many tools like Classic Color Meter, etc which will tell you the hex color value of something your mouse is rolling over.